# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql-error-2013

A strange thing is happening which I am not able to understand

When I fire the below query I am getting error 2013:

Query: select * from userMaster order by id desc limit 5;

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

But moment I either change the limit clause or add a where clause it starts working:

e.g. select * from userMaster order by id desc limit 5,5; - this works

Answer (score 3):

This problem maybe happened when upgrade mysql5.5 to 5.6.

Just run:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Then it may be normal.

Reference: [Upgrading MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html)